# jQuery externs file for 1.10.x or 2.0.x?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

As far as I can tell there is no official jQuery externs file for the 1.10 or 2.0 branch of jQuery. My question is, am I going to run into trouble using the jQuery 1.9 externs file with the 1.10 and 2.0 versions?

Answer (score 6):

**//Update**

As @John pointed out, you are better off using the 1.9 externs until 1.10 is available.

If you are missing externs for other libraries then jQuery, and you are not interested in type checking, you could try providing a library itself as an extern for closure compiler.

```
--externs some-library.js
```

and suppressing the warnings:

```
--jscomp_off=externsValidation
```

However, be careful with this method. After switching to `VERBOSE` mode I run into problems [like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057870/closure-compiler-syntheticvarsdeclar-warning-redeclared-variable)

Comment: This will provide you with a very poor extern definitions. You are better off using the 1.9 externs until 1.10 is available.

Comment: @John Thank you for your comment, it is interesting, I didn't know that. Can you elaborate please? Why this will give poor extern definitions?

Comment: jquery is generally written in a way where most of the functionality is opaque to the compiler.  The official jQuery externs also provide type information so you use of jQuery methods will be type checked.

Comment: @John Apart of jQuery methods not being type checked, are there any  more drawbacks? I am guessing the minification will be slightly less efficient?

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'll just stick with an older version of jQuery that has an official externs file.

Comment: @John I updated the answer. Please feel free to edit it, if there anything incorrect. Or if you prefer to post a new answer I will delete this one.

Comment: In lieu of any better answers and the fact that there still isn't an externs file for 2.x I'm going to mark this as the answer.