# Closure Compiler - {SyntheticVarsDeclar}: WARNING - Redeclared variable

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am using Closure Compiler with `--warning_level=VERBOSE` and `--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

It outputs:

```
{SyntheticVarsDeclar}: WARNING - Redeclared variable: i
0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Is there a way to find out more information about where this `i` variable is declared?

**//Update**

I have run through every `i` variable in all the files and there is none that are redeclared.

Here is a list of flags being used:

`--jscomp_off=externsValidation`

`--summary_detail_level=3`

`--warning_level=VERBOSE`

`--externs`

`--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

`--output_wrapper`

`--source_map_format`

`--js_output_file`

**//Update 2**

I am using the latest Closure Compiler from:
http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip

When I add a "var i" at the top of the first file, the compiler comes back with:

```
firstFile.js:1: WARNING - Redeclared variable: i
var i;
    ^
```

and there is no previous {SyntheticVarsDeclar} warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the --third_party flag is not being used.  Nothing should be added as {SyntheticVarsDeclar} unless the declaration is missing.  The --third_party flag cause missing global variables declarations to be "declared" in "{SyntheticVarsDeclar}".

Comment: --third_party flag is not being used. I updated the question.

Comment: Two things: (1) verify you are using the latest release of the compiler. (2) As an experiment, add a "var i" at the top of the first file.

Comment: (1) Yes, I am using the latest Closure Compiler. (2) I updated the question with the new info.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have an extern file with some JS code in it rather than simply stub declarations?  And that extern doesn't have "i" declared in something like:

Comment: Do you see this same problem with just your externs and a single file "var i"? (to rule out the sources as the problem)?  Can you share your extra externs?

Comment: Yes, the externs where the problem. I am migrating an application to get it to work with VERBOSE mode by adding annotations for type checking etc. I could not find externs for some of libraries we are using. Temporarily I am using few libraries themselves as externs. One of the libraries had: `for ( i in iterable )`. Adding `var` solved the warning. I am going to sort out these externs. I should have listened to your comments on the other externs question. I had to learn in the hard way I guess :) Thank you for your time John, much appreciated.